# Where in the gospel and the bible is prophet muhammed mentioned

Tags: islam, gospel

Where in the Gospel and the bible is Prophet Muhammad mentioned it mentioned in the Quran that he is mentioned?

Comment: The name of Muhammad is NEVER mentioned in either the Old Testament or the New Testament (which contains the gospels of Christ Jesus, the Son of God). This question (and my answer) may address what you are looking for: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/78642/does-the-verse-in-song-of-solomon-516-contain-the-name-of-the-islamic-prophet-m?rq=1

Comment: @Lesley You are lying Prophet Muhammad must be mentioned in the bible and the old testamente

Comment: Please don't accuse me of lying.  I've done extensive research into this subject and have been studying the Bible for 40 years. Muhammad is not mentioned.

Comment: @Lesley - The two passages that Muslims _claim_ to be referring to Mohammed are Song of Songs (also called Song of Solomon or "Canticles") chapter 5 verse 16 and Gospel of John, chapters 14 to 16, which I strongly recommend you read for yourself, to see the context of John 14:16-17, 14:26; 15:26; 16:13.  As for Song 5:16, if he is mentioned here then he is also mentioned in other passages of the Old Testament. See youtube video featuring Zakir Naik and David Wood "Is Muhammed mentioned by name in the Song of Solomon?

Comment: @AndrewShanks  Appreciate your input and I will check out those Bible verses.

Comment: @Lesley - So David Wood points out if Song 5:16 is referring to Muhammed then so is Ezekiel 24:16 (which would then mean that Muhammed was Ezekiel's wife(! ... er... NOT) and also in 2 Chronicles 36:19 where talking of the Babylonian destruction under Nebuchadnezzer - "and burnt all the fine buildings thereof [in Jerusalem] with fire, and 'destroyed all the Muhammeds of it' or 'destroyed all the fine vessels of it'".  Finally Muslims claim that Deuteronomy 18:15 "I will raise a prophet from your midst from your brethren" is referring to Muhammed... of course it refers to Christ (Acts 3:22).